# Make surrounding elements zero in a matrix, when you find a zero value

Tags: java, loops, matrix, traversal

Please can you **suggest** a better / **Optimized** logic or code for the question. It has been asked that when you find a zero value in a matrix, make that element the sum of its upper, lower ,left, right value and make the upper, lower ,left, right elements zero. I assume to the matrix provided has at least 2 rows and 2 columns but if you can post code for any type of matrix , it would be of utmost help. I have fully **commented** the code for easy understanding, just **copy and paste** it in editor and **tweak the values of the matrix variable in the main function of the program**.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    static void MakeSurroundingElementsZero(int i,int j,int[][]matrix){
        //when the element is not on the boundary of matrix.means it has
        // all surrounding elements
        if(i >0 && i < matrix.length-1 && j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1){
             matrix[i][j-1]=matrix[i][j+1]=matrix[i-1][j]=matrix[i+1][j]=0;
        }
        //when it is in the first row
        else if(i ==0){
            // when it is not the first or last element in the first row
            if(j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1){
                 matrix[i][j+1]=matrix[i][j-1]=matrix[i+1][j]=0;
            }
            //when it is the first element of the first row
            else if(j ==0){
                 matrix[i][j+1]=matrix[i+1][j]=0;
            }
            // when it is the last element of the first row
            else{
                matrix[i][j-1]=matrix[i+1][j]=0;
            }
        }
        //when the element is present in the last row
        else{
            //element not the last or the first in the last row
            if (j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1 ){
                matrix[i][j+1]=matrix[i-1][j]=matrix[i][j-1]=0;
            }
            //first element in the last row
            else if (j==0){
                matrix[i-1][j]=matrix[i][j+1]=0;
            }
            //last element of the last row
            else{
                matrix[i][j-1]=matrix[i-1][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    static void addElements(int i,int j,int[][]matrix){
        //when the element is not on the boundary of matrix.means it has
        // all surrounding elements
        if(i >0 && i < matrix.length-1 && j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1){
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i+1][j];
        }
        //when it is in the first row
        else if(i ==0){
            // when it is not the first or last element in the first row
            if(j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1){
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j];
            }
            //when it is the first element of the first row
            else if(j ==0){
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i+1][j];
            }
            // when it is the last element of the first row
            else{
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i+1][j];
            }
        }
        //when the element is present in the last row
        else{
            //element not the last or the first in the last row
            if (j >0 && j < matrix[i].length-1 ){
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j+1]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i][j-1];
            }
            //first element in the last row
            else if (j==0){
                matrix[i][j]= matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i][j+1];
            }
            //last element of the last row
            else{
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    static void MakeZeroes(int[][] matrix) {
        ArrayList<Integer[]> zeroElements = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        for (int i = 0;i < matrix.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j < matrix[i].length;j++){
                //checking each element for zero value
                if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
                    addElements(i,j,matrix);
                    //store it as we haven't made the surrounding elements zero yet

                    Integer[] zeroelem = {i,j};
                    zeroElements.add(zeroelem);

                }
            }
        }
        //finally, make surrounding elements zero
        for (int i = 0;i<zeroElements.size();i++){

                MakeSurroundingElementsZero(zeroElements.get(i)[0],zeroElements.get(i)[1],matrix);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = {{2,0,4,0},
                          {5,9,7,9},
                          {2,0,8,0}};
        MakeZeroes(matrix);
        for (int i =0;i < matrix.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

My approach is to:-

- Go to each element.
- Check if it is zero or not.
- If zero, then check where that element lies , whether totally inside the matrix or on the boundary.
- Add accordingly the elements around that zero value element.
- Store the index of that zero element in an ArrayList.
- Loop the ArrayList to make the surrounding elements zero.

Comment: When you encounter the first `0`, the answer is `15` based on the rules. But as you scan you don't seem to be taking into account the values that were previously set to zero when `15` was computed.  This appears to include detecting the next `0` or summing adjacent elements which could have been previously changed.  In any event, this is probably best addressed in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not StackOverflow.

Comment: No WJS ,  just put it in the editor and you will see that i have done exactly the same as you are telling me, i hit the same thought as you have just told me thats why i wrote a lengthy program Please run it and see.

Comment: thanks for telling me about code review